# How to chain command line function in Python file open() like Perl does?

Tags: python, file

We are in the process of rewriting a lot of Perl code in our infrastructure to Python.  The syntax is similar and it reads similarly.  However, there are a number of subtle differences that makes the conversion a bit challenging.

We have a command-line utility in our Linux environment called "read_file".  You pass a pathname to a file and read_file will determine how to open it and "read" from it.  You can pass in a *.txt, *.dat, *.gz, *.bz2, *.pgp and even a *.zip (as long as there is only 1 file in the zip archive) and read_file will determine how to unzip/decrypt and pass a stream of human-readable output.

We leverage this a lot in our Perl programs and opening a file is as simple as:

```
my $fh = IO::File->new();
$fh->open("read_file $file_name |") or abend_pgm("open: $!");
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
  ...
}
```

This causes Perl to drop to the shell, start up a "read_file  " and its output is piped in as the input to the $fh->open(), so that the Perl script sees only the unzipped/decrypted text without any special handling.

**Is there a similar way in Python to accomplish this?**

Also, is there a similar thing that can be done with the writes, so that the output from Python open() is piped through let's say, "gzip" directly?  In Perl it's done like this:

```
open (my $fh, "| /usr/bin/gzip -c > $file_name ");
```

This opens a file for output, anything emitted to the $fh file handle will be piped to /usr/bin/gzip -c and the zipped output is redirected to the $file_name.  All of the conversions is handled by Perl and the OS rather than the script, which makes it very simple to leverage the huge library of functions available in Linux itself.

Is this something I will have to do a popen() and read from that output?

---

I have tried this and variations upon this, and could not figure out what else can be done:

```
>>> with open(" /ds/CENTOS/common/bin/read_file /ds/tmp/177598.TEST_20240225.dat.gz","r") as file1:
...   read_content = file1.read()
...   print(read_content)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ' /ds/CENTOS/common/bin/read_file /ds/tmp/177598.NATL_340B_20240225.dat.gz'
>>>
```

In Perl, I can access this file just fine and it'll unzip and print the file to the screen:

```
perl -e 'my $fh = IO::File->new(); $fh->open("/ds/CENTOS/common/bin/read_file /ds/tmp/177598.TEST_20240225.dat.gz |"); while (my $line = <$fh>) { print $line; };'
```

Comment: Perl `open` does a lot of stuff that is really more akin to what the `subprocess` module does.

Comment: Even in Perl, it's been recommended for years that you use something like `open my $fh, "-|", "read_file", $file_name` instead of `open my $fh, "read_file $file_name |"`.

Answer (score 1):

There are more recent methods for doing this in Python, which offer several ways of dealing with buffering/errors in the remote process - at the cost of no little boiler plate and complications.

But Python still keeps the bureaucracy-free way to do that, which is `os.popen`:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: print(os.popen("gunzip -c debuginfo.json.gz").read())
{
 "App": "com.whatsapp.w4b",
 "Architecture": "aarch64",
 "Board": "sm6150",
 "Build": "RP1A.200720.012.A705MNXXS5DWH1",
 "CCode": " ",
 "CPU ABI": "arm64-v8a",
(...)
```

if you ever need the more controlled variants of Popen, introduced in the early 2000's, check the docs for the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: "bureaucracy-free"? You're handing off vague instructions to a separate component (the shell) following a bunch of arcane rules [dating back decades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) that may or may not be what you want (and indeed, if you didn't [dot your i's and cross your t's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote), may do things [directly contrary to what you want](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Command_Injection)). That seems like bureaucracy to me.

Comment: so, whoever wants to control the ts, is, and such, is free to use subprocess.Popen with all the paraphernalia it carries. :-)  The equivalent simple expression to the Perl way is this one. 
Fact is that since its inception supprocess has had a terrible API, worse documentation, and the introduction of `.run` in Python 3.5 did just a little to ease the status quo.

Comment: In the analogy above, `subprocess` is getting under the hood and doing the work yourself, and thus having the control to be certain it's done exactly as you like. This may be different for more Windows-y folks, but as someone familiar with the underlying interfaces being called through to on UNIX, `subprocess.Popen` seems entirely intuitive and sensible to me.

Comment: Great, if it also does for the O.P., the links are in the answer. You are welcome to add a second example in the answer using subprocess.Popen, and reword my quick critics to it.  (this is a direct invitation)

Answer (score 1):

Perl's `open` function allows for a lot of things that are more akin to what the `subprocess` module in Python is designed for. Python `open` is for opening files, not executing arbitrary shell pipelines.

For example,

```perl
my $fh = IO::File->new();
$fh->open("read_file $file_name |") or abend_pgm("open: $!");
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
  ...
}
```

becomes

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["read_file", file_name], stdout=PIPE)
(stdout, _) = p.communicate()
for line in stdout:
    ...
```

The call to `Popen` could fail to start `read_file` at all, or `read_file` could exit with an error. The former usually produces an exception you would need to catch; the latter would be detected by checking `p.returncode` directly.

Comment: Is `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` no longer needed here?

Comment: It probably is. It's been so long since I've actually used `communicate`, I forgot to check. (I was originally not going to use `communicate` here, which is why `PIPE` is still being imported.)

Answer (score 1):

Python standard library contains tools for working with various types of compressed files, as described in [Data Compression and Archiving](https://docs.python.org/3/library/archiving.html). They often could be used like `open` built-in. Take for example [reading .gz files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#examples-of-usage) firstly let create such file

```
echo "ABLE BAKER CHARLIE" > file.txt
gzip file.txt
```

then we can do in python

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'rb') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
print(file_content)
```

gives output

```
b'ABLE BAKER CHARLIE\n'
```

Keep in mind determining *which* device from standard library to use w.r.t to file is up to you. Note you get bytes as `file_content` if you wish to get text you should `.decode` it.